# Incomplete name match to complete name using Python

Tags: python, matching

I have a list in a column. It goes like this for example:

```
powderA1992
powderA199
creamB2001
creamB200
```

Assuming the correct data points are `powederA1992` and `creamB2000`.

How do I match, and replace in a new column for `powderA199` to match to `powderA1992`?

Small sample in this question but I do have 60k entries.

Here is my code:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

sellers= dataset['seller_name']
sellers = sellers.dropna()

print (sellers.head(10))

sellers2 = sellers.copy()
sellers2.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=False)
print (sellers2.head(10))

print(len(sellers))
print (len(sellers2))

def match_term(term, list_names,min_score=0):
    max_score = -1
    max_name = ""
    for term2 in list_names:
        score = fuzz.ratio(term, term2)
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = term2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)

for i in sellers:
    print (i, match_term(i, sellers2,20))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show an example of the required output.  Have you looked into combining pandas and regex?

Comment: @S3DEV thanks for your reply. I haven't done regex. I tried FuzzyWuzzy.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but your function `match_term` is already part of fuzzywuzzy as `process.extractOne(i, sellers2, score_cutoff=20, scorer=fuzz.ratio, processor=None)`

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the data your handling. When it is really just substrings like you show in your question why not just iterate over the list and replace all strings that are substrings?